# How to get Discord 0.0.2 to work on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation

Today I was unable to open Discord without updating it to the 0.0.2 version. I attempted to install it using the .deb file but when clicking on "install", nothing happened. So I installed it using the .tar.gz file with these commands:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/discord/discord.desktop /usr/share/applications/
sudo ln -s /usr/share/discord/discord.png /usr/share/icons/
sudo ln -s /usr/share/discord/Discord /usr/bin/discord
```

When I opened the application I just got a blank screen:
[Screenshot of Discord 0.0.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9AHS.png)

Comment: Are the permissions on this executable right? Why don't you just run the `/usr/share/discord/Discord` or the desktop file (look what's inside maybe paths aren't right) and see if it works. The thing you did atm. was only creating symlinks.

Comment: I ran the executable, same result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I encountered the same issue today. Here is how I managed to solve it.

1. Remove discord
2. Download the discord .deb file and install it:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i my_discord_deb_file.deb
   ```
3. fix missing dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```
4. re-run:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i my_discord_deb_file.deb
   ```

N.B: I don't know if all the steps are necessary, but it worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me! The [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line) had a lot of information on it, but this answer completely solved the problem for me.